# factor of covering map is a covering map?

Tags: general-topology

A paper I'm trying to understand uses the following lemma:

Let $p: U \to U_0$ be a topological covering map.  Suppose that we can write $p =\pi \circ f$, where $f:U \to Y$ is an open surjective map, and $\pi: Y \to U_0$ is continuous.  Then $f$ is also a topological covering map.

It seems like the proof should be very straightforward, but I can't get it to work out. I think I can prove it in the case of finite degree covering maps.

Comment: maybe sketch your proof for the finite degree map, and see where it might go wrong?

Comment: @Henno Given a point $y\in Y$, consider an evenly covered nbd $N\subset Z$ containing $\pi(y)$.  Suppose $N$ is evenly covered by $V_1,\ldots,V_n \subset V$.  Then taking the intersection of all $g(V_i)\subset Y$ that contain $y$ gives an evenly covered nbd of $y$.